# Dropdownlist asp.net not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

I have the following mark-up:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTownships" DataTextField="Name" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataValueField="Id" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTownships_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Please select a township"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

and this is the code behind:

```
protected void ddlRegions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var townshipDAO = (TownshipDAO)FactoryDAO.getInstance().getDAOByType(DAOEnum.Township);
            ddlTownships.DataSource = townshipDAO.getAllTownshipsByRegionId(Int64.Parse(ddlRegions.SelectedValue));
            ddlTownships.DataBind();
            liTownships.Visible = true;
            liSettlements.Visible = false;
            divPhasesConsole.Visible = false;
            liNumberOfStands.Visible = false;
            divFirstDelimiter.Visible = false;
        }
```

Basically whenever a user selects an item from the ddlRegion, I get all townships with the regionId selected and repopulate the dropdownlist. However the ddlTownships remembers the previously selected townships with different regions. Note that I have the property AppendDataBoundItems="True" because that was the only way I could add a list item that says "Please select a township". How can I leave the listitem defined in the mark-up and prevent the previous items from showing up after the ddl is repopulated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do You insert any times into those `DropDownList` in `Page_Init` or `Page_Load` events? In order to make this code to work, you shouldn't add items in `ddlRegions_SelectedIndexChanged`, but rather check for a selected item in `Page_Init` and repopulate the second list based on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a new list item at a particular index from the code behind. So you could remove `AppendDataBoundItems` and add this after the databinding:

```
ddlTownships.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem() { Text = "Please select a township", Value = "0" });
```

Another helpful thing to know is that can clear out the list before databinding:

```
ddlTownships.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: yea i figured out the insert() method in the meantime. However your answer is correct. Thanks